# How to change time zome in different tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Can you give an idea? 
I have two tables in to postgresql DB. 
The are filled with recods by two separate csv files. But the records of the first csv file are with local timestamp. The second csv file is with timestamps UTC. 
So I need to change the time in local of the view in this table that is filled with records with timezone UTC. I used to deal with that problem before using laravel with this code in every page that I need to do that, for example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');
```

The controller:

```
      function getdata_chart(Request $request)
      {
        $start_date = date('d-m-Y 00:00:00');
        $end_date = date('d-m-Y 23:59:59');
        if($request->start_date != '' && $request->end_date != '')
        {
          // if user fill dates
          $dateScope = array($request->start_date ." 00:00:00", $request->end_date ." 23:59:59");
        } else {
          // default load page - today
          $dateScope = array($start_date, $end_date);
        };
        $students = MeasCanal::whereBetween('recordtime', $dateScope)
      ->selectRaw('recordtime')
      ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = \'Данни.Кота\') as iazovir')
      ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = \'Данни.Температура\') as temperatura350')
      ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('fullname', 'like', "Язовир.Данни.Кота")
              ->orWhere('fullname', 'like', "ГСК_11_350.Данни.Температура");
      })
      ->groupBy('recordtime')
      ->orderBy('recordtime')
      ->get();

        return response()->json($students);

      }
    return response()->json($students);
}
```

Comment: check here -https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-and-mysql-timezone

Comment: if you need to change the default timezone , change it on config/app.php  , you will find the key : timezone change it to Europe/Sofia

Comment: no I need to change it only in the second table

Comment: If you don't need UTC time stamps than just create a script to update all UTC timestamps to local timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Model MeasCanal  and add the following  :

Import and use :

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Add Function :

```
/**
     * Get the user's recordtime.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRecordtimeAttribute($value)
    {
            return Carbon::parse($value)->timezone('Europe/Sofia')->toDateTimeString();

    }
```

Comment: Any example how to import it in the controller above, please?

Comment: just edit you Model : MeasCanal with the suggested information without changing your controller , I suppose it will work

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you very mutch. For now it is working great!

Comment: happy that it is working for you , good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you want but i think you can get the idea.

**First Method,**

You can use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators);

```
public function getCustomTimestampAttribute($value)
{
    // you can use your logic here to set your timezone by table
    $timezone = 'Europe/Sofia';
    return Carbon::parse($this->custom_timestamp)->timezone($timezone)->toDateTimeString();
}
```

then you can get the value like: `$model->custom_timestamp`

**Second Method,**

You can use [map](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map);

```
$customDates = $dates->map(function ($date, $key) {
    $date->custom_timestamp = Carbon::parse($date->custom_timestamp)->timezone('Europe/Sofia')->toDateTimeString();
    return $date;
});
```

**EDIT**

In your model(MeasCanal) set recordtime attribute;

```
public function getRecordtimeAttribute($value)
{
    // you can use your logic here to set your timezone by table
    $timezone = 'Europe/Sofia';
    return Carbon::parse($this->recordtime)->timezone($timezone)->toDateTimeString();
}
```

then you can simply see the result after the query in your controller like

`dd($students);`

or even simpler to see:

`dd($students->first()->recordtime); // first matched rows recordtime attr.`

**Note:** you cant use accessors with raw queries you should use eloquent models btw.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I edited my post. The timestamp is with column name `recordtime`. Can you make an example using my function and your first method, please?

Comment: I updated my answer but just realized you are sending response as json. In this case i suggest you to use "map".