# Get current date records from table with different time zone

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

This question is related to my previews one: [How to change time zome in different tables in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635641/how-to-change-time-zome-in-different-tables-in-laravel)

After I mark the answer, discover a problem:

When user load the page it need to gives him records for the current day.

For example from 00:00:00 to now.

The problem is that the controller is asking the DB to give records from 00:00:00 in UTC, after this my model(in the link above) parsing it to LOCAL time.

This local time is Europe/Sofia (+3 hours), causing to miss 3 records from today starting with 03:00:00.

Any idea how to fix it?

The controller:

```
      function getdata_chart(Request $request)
      {
        $start_date = date('d-m-Y 00:00:00');
        $end_date = date('d-m-Y 23:59:59');
        if($request->start_date != '' && $request->end_date != '')
        {
          // if user fill dates
          $dateScope = array($request->start_date ." 00:00:00", $request->end_date ." 23:59:59");
        } else {
          // default load page - today
          $dateScope = array($start_date, $end_date);
        };
        $students = MeasCanal::whereBetween('recordtime', $dateScope)
      ->selectRaw('recordtime')
      ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = \'Данни.Кота\') as iazovir')
      ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = \'Данни.Температура\') as temperatura350')
      ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('fullname', 'like', "Язовир.Данни.Кота")
              ->orWhere('fullname', 'like', "ГСК_11_350.Данни.Температура");
      })
      ->groupBy('recordtime')
      ->orderBy('recordtime')
      ->get();

        return response()->json($students);

      }
    return response()->json($students);
}
```

The model:

```
class MeasCanal extends Model
{
  protected $connection = 'MeasCanal';
  protected $table = 'meas_kanal';
  protected $fillable = ['fullname','formattedvalue','recordtime','qualitydesc','statedesc','id'];


  /**
       * Get the user's recordtime.
       *
       * @param  string  $value
       * @return string
       */
      public function getRecordtimeAttribute($value)
      {
              return Carbon::parse($value)->timezone('Europe/Sofia')->toDateTimeString();

      }
}
```

Comment: can you show some code? As in your last question, you just change the value of the attribute by defining an accessor.

Comment: Ok the code is added.

Comment: Ok. let me check.

Comment: I have added the answer. You can check and implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map the user input date from the DB timezone to the user timezone by calling the carbon method and array map function. and call the query as it is.

```
function getdata_chart(Request $request) {
    $start_date = date('d-m-Y 00:00:00');
    $end_date = date('d-m-Y 23:59:59');

    if($request->start_date != '' && $request->end_date != '')
    {
        // if user fill dates
        $dateScope = array($request->start_date ." 00:00:00", $request->end_date ." 23:59:59");
    } else {
        // default load page - today
        $dateScope = array($start_date, $end_date);
    };


    $dbTimeZone = 'Asia/Kolkata'; // update with your db timezone
    $userTimeZone = 'Europe/Sofia';

    $dateScope = array_map(function($date) use ($dbTimeZone, $userTimeZone) {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $date, $dbTimeZone)->setTimezone($userTimeZone);
    }, $dateScope);

    $students = MeasCanal::whereBetween('recordtime', $dateScope)
                ->selectRaw('recordtime')
                ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = \'Данни.Кота\') as iazovir')
                ->selectRaw('max(formattedvalue) filter (where fullname = \'Данни.Температура\') as temperatura350')
                ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('fullname', 'like', "Язовир.Данни.Кота")
                      ->orWhere('fullname', 'like', "ГСК_11_350.Данни.Температура");
                })
                ->groupBy('recordtime')
                ->orderBy('recordtime')
                ->get();

    return response()->json($students);

    }
    return response()->json($students);
}
```

**Note that:-** add the following line to the controller if you are not using carbon til yet.

> use Carbon\Carbon;

Comment: The code working only when user not have interaction. But what code to bind for $dbTimeZone because the DB is in UTC. If the user pick a date the fallowing error is displayed:""Unexpected data found.
↵Unexpected data found.
↵Data missing""

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php. search your timezone from here

Comment: Or show the output of the "$request->start_date" and "$request->end_date" value when the user interacts with your form

Comment: I know the time zone is UTC. But when bind it to $dbTimeZone = 'UTC'; it givimg me 06:00:00 am

Comment: My question is what is the value and the type of the start_date and end_date variables while posting the request. It should be a string like start_date = "10-04-2020" and end_date = "10-04-2020"

Comment: Which variable value gives you the "06:00:00 am".

Comment: I think your code does not work if user select a date. This is the exception: "InvalidArgumentException"

Comment: I am still asking the same question what is the value and the type of the start_date and end_date variables while posting the request? add this code  in controller print_r($request->all()); and show the output...

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException. "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211346/discussion-between-sachin-kumar-and-hristian-yordanov).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that date separator was different on each fuction causing `Unexpected data found.`. After edit him the answer of  Sachin Kumar did the job. Thanks for that. 
Just discover the problem with similar long way solution:

```
  $start_date0 = date('d-m-Y 00:00:00');
  $end_date0 = date('d-m-Y 23:59:59');

  $start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $start_date0, 'Europe/Sofia')->setTimezone('UTC');
  $end_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $end_date0, 'Europe/Sofia')->setTimezone('UTC');


  if($request->start_date != '' && $request->end_date != '')
  {
    // if user fill dates
    $start_date0 = $request->start_date;
    $end_date0 = $request->end_date;
    $start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $start_date0, 'Europe/Sofia')->setTimezone('UTC');
    $end_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $end_date0, 'Europe/Sofia')->setTimezone('UTC');
    $dateScope = array($start_date, $end_date);
  } else {
    // default load page - today
    $dateScope = array($start_date, $end_date);
  };
```